# how to use IF statement inside another IF statement to solve complicated calculation

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

The question is taken from http://www.programmr.com/node/137861/begin
and you can test it there.

I am writing a program which displays an appropriate name for a person, using a combination of nested if's and compound conditions. Ask the user for a gender, first name, last name and age.

If the person is female and 20 or over, ask if she is married. If so, display "Mrs." in front of her name. If not, display "Ms." in front of her name. If the female is under 20, display her first and last name.

If the person is male and 20 or over, display "Mr." in front of his name. Otherwise, display his first and last name.

Note that asking a person if they are married should only be done if they are female and 20 or older.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$finalName;
echo "What is your Gender (M or F):";
$gender = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "First Name:";
$firstName = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Last Name:";
$lastName = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Age:";
$age = trim(fgets(STDIN));

if ($gender == "M" and $age>19) {
    $finalName = "Mr. ".$lastName;
}

if ($age<20) {
    $finalName = $firstName.$lastName;
}

if ($gender == "F" and $age>19) {
    echo "Are you married:";
    $married = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    if ($married == "Y") {
        $finalName = "Mrs. ".$lastName;
    }
    else {
        $finalName = "Ms. ".$lastName;
    }
}

echo "Then I will call you ".$finalName;
exit;
?>
```

The code does not give expected output. Is there something wrong in the logic or does if statement not work this way ?

Comment: `=` is the **assignment** operator, `==` is the test for equality.

Comment: For one thing, all your `ifs` such as `if ($gender = "F"` are wrong which should use `==` instead of just `=` Plus your initial `$finalName;` is not yet assigned, so no point in having that there, right off the bat (as it were) @deceze beats me by 7 seconds lol

Comment: I just cleaned up the indentation in your code. This is how it should have looked. Please make sure to indent your future code properly and consistently!

Comment: I have made the necessary changes as suggested in the code - still it does not work ?

Comment: Plus you're going to get this error on lines 4, 6 and 10 `Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in...` so your code scored a perfect "FAIL". There is nothing else for code to further test it. You're missing another piece of code to make it "work", as `fgets` is looking for something, but is not finding it in your posted code. Where is the accompanying form to go with this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- you can test it here : http://www.programmr.com/node/137861/begin

Comment: @RahinaRakhi What is your question then? This looks to me like it's Ruby or written in C and requires additional libraries to run. It's only an online exercise, far as I can tell it takes user input to output to screen. You can achieve similar results by using a standard form and handler.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So the code I have written is right :)

Comment: @RahinaRakhi Seems like it. If you're not getting error messages, and it works as intended, then we're done here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is what worked. I replaced = with == in the if statement.

I also replace "and" with "&&" in the if statement and it worked like a charm.

```
     if ($gender == "M" && $age>19) {
    $finalName = "Mr. ".$lastName;
}

if ($age<20) {
    $finalName = $firstName." ".$lastName;
}

if ($gender == "F" && $age>19) {
    echo "Are you married:";
    $married = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    if ($married == "Y") {
        $finalName = ("Mrs. ".$lastName);
    }
    else {
        $finalName = ("Ms. ".$lastName);
    }
}
```